# R.prop('parentNode', R.__) returns a function

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I had write a function **init** which should to get a className relative to **align** property and set this className to a parentNode. But I receive a function instead of parentNode.

```js
const addClass = R.curry((className, el) => {
    console.log(className) //=> String
    console.log(el) //=> Function ???

    R.forEach(
        R.call(R.invoker(1, 'add'), R.__, el.classList),
        R.split(', ', className)
    )
})

const getAlignClassName = R.compose(
    R.cond([
        [R.equals('left'), R.always('video--align-left')],
        [R.equals('right'), R.always('video--align-right')],
        [R.T, R.always('video--align-center')]
    ]),
    R.prop('align')
)

const init = R.call(
    addClass,
    getAlignClassName(R.__),
    R.prop('parentNode', R.__)
    //R.prop('parentNode') // this one also returns a function
)

const tmp = { align: 'left', parentNode: 'some parent node' }

console.log(init(tmp))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ramda/latest/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just replaced **R.call** with **R.converge**. So, it's working now)